# Retrieve limited rows from single column from mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am trying to retrieve only last 3 recently added rows from single column from MySql database. Please help in this--

my jsp code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.* "%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<% Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eco", "root", "vicky");
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from registration");
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
rs.afterLast();

while(rs.previous()){ %>
<p>  <%= rs.getString(2) %> </p>
<%} %>
</body>
</html>
```

my database structure:

```
 ID   username   email                  password
    1   vikas      vikas5@gmail.com        44
    2   Aravind    Aravind@gmail.com       12
    3   rakesh     rakesh@gmail.com        123
    4   chandra    chnadra@gmail.com       123
    5   shiva      chinthala@gmail.com     12345
    6   sai         sai@gmail.com          4321
    7   ravi         ravi@gmail.com        987654
```

The ouput getting for me

```
ravi
sai
shiva
chandra
rakesh
Aravind
vikas
```

but i want output as

```
ravi        sai      shiva  
chandra   rakesh     Aravind  
vikas
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Order By with Limit](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/).

- `Order by ID DESC` sorts the data in descending order based on `ID` column.
- `LIMIT 3` gets the first 3 rows in the sorted data.

Change the following:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from registration");
```

to

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from registration order by ID desc limit 3");
```

Comment: If I understood OP's question properly, there is an issue of retrieving **the last n inputs** in the table, not related to **ID** (except the ID is auto-increment)

Comment: @zlakad "last 3 recently added rows from single column" - since ID is auto increment - it is fair to assume that last 3 added rows will having the first 3 id values in descending order

Comment: I understand this, but **what if** ID is not auto increment?

Comment: @zlakad then god save OP's database structure. nevertheless, as per his expected output, my current query should work for the given sample data and expected output

Comment: Oh, well, I agree.

Comment: I changed my output order please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only the last 3 records, then you need to change your query.

You have to write a nested query like this:

SELECT *
FROM (select * from registration ORDER BY ID) registration
WHERE rownum <= 3
ORDER BY rownum DESC;

Please refer to the following link for further information:

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/bottom_records.php

https://www.techonthenet.com

this is very nice and very helpfull site to learn Database and other technology.

i hope it  will help you

and also you can do it 
this query is also work

SELECT * FROM registration ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 3;